# Did Mordechai have a different "scream" than Moshe Rabbeinu?

Tags: tefilla, purim, yetziat-mitzrayim, egypt, mordechai

What are some of the differences between the word וַיִּצְעַק and וַיִּזְעַק?

**וַיִּצְעַק** Here:

( https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.8.8?ven=Metsudah_Chumash,_Metsudah_Publications,_2009&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

**וַיִּזְעַק** Here:

(https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.4.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

To further add to this question, in [Bereishis Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.67.4?lang=bi&with=Likutei%20Moharan&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B0%D7%9E%D6%B9%D7%A2%D6%B7%20%D7%A2%D6%B5%D7%A9%D7%82%D6%B8%D7%95%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%20%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%91%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B5%D7%99%20%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%91%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%95%D6%B7%D7%99%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%96%D6%B0%D7%A2%D6%B7%D7%A7%20%D7%96%D6%B0%D7%A2%D6%B8%D7%A7%D6%B8%D7%94) where it seems to use the words interchangeably which leads me to believe that there might not be any actual difference between the two - which begs the question of why its necessary to have both words if they are truly 100% the same.

Comment: I'll do you one better: https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.27.34?lang=bi

Comment: I am pretty sure rav hirsh discusses this

Comment: Esther Rabbah 8:1 makes that link with Esau. Yaakov Aavinu made Esau cry, so Hashem repaid him eventually by making Mordechai cry.

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy please provide any sources that i can follow up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questioner asked about the differences between the words צעק and זעק which we can also add to the question what this has to do with צחק – laughter. Rav Samson Refoel Hersch addressed this question and practically explains that there is no difference. This is found in Parshas Lech Lecha. Genesis 17:17, Here is the Hebrew with an English translation (translated from the original German by Chat GPT)

> מכחישה שצחקה, וה' לא היה גוער בה. "צחק", "שׂחק", "צעק", "זעק", "שאג"
> הם שרשים קרובים, אך הם מציינים לכאורה דברים הפוכים. השורשים שהאות
> האמצעית שלהם היא ע' או א' – מציינים צעקה, ואילו אותם שהאות האמצעית
> שלהם היא ח' – מציינים צחוק. מהו הבסיס המשותף לשתי התופעות השונות האלה
> (צעקה וצחוק)? שתיהן מתעוררות כשנפגשים הפכים מנוגדים שאין כל שייכות
> ביניהם: מנקודת מבט עניינית [אובייקטיבית] מתעורר אז "צחוק"; וכשנוגע
> הדבר למישהו באופן אישי מתעוררת "צעקה". הבחנה בסתירה פנימית ובאי־התאמה
> בדבר שאינו קשור אלינו – אף אם הניתוק הוא זמני בלבד – גורמת לנו לצחוק;
> אך אם אי ההתאמה פוגע בנו אישית, או פוגע במי שאנו חשים כלפיו קירבה
> רגשית ומשתתפים בשמחתו ובצערו, הרי שאנו צועקים. ילד קטן החובש פאה
> נכרית, זקן שיש עליו חיתול כתינוק, וכדומה, מביאים לצחוק; וכן גם המרחק
> הגדול שבין ציפייה, תפקיד, או ביצוע, לבין האמצעים העומדים לשם כך; או
> המרחק שבין התוצאות המצופות ובין מה שנוכל לעשות בפועל. הבא למדוד את מי
> הים בכף ידו, או אדם מבוגר המוֹעֵד ונופל, גורם לנו לצחוק; אך אם יש לנו
> קירבה עם אותו אדם ואנו משתתפים בצערו או בושתו, אנו חשים בצורך לצעוק.

> שאג (shout), זעק (cry out), צעק (scream), שחק (laugh), צחק (laughter),
> are evidently related roots in terms of sound, yet they seemingly mean
> opposite things; those with the middle letter ע and א: to shout, with
> ח: to laugh. What is the common basic concept behind these seemingly
> completely different phenomena? Both are caused by perceived or felt
> contrasts, that is, improperly paired opposites; objectively, this
> produces laughter, subjectively: screaming. Perceiving such a contrast
> in an object that is foreign to us or temporarily foreign evokes
> laughter; a more fitting contrast that involves ourselves or a
> personality identified with ourselves makes us scream. A small child
> with a wig, an elderly person as a baby, etc., generates laughter.
> Similarly, the complete disproportion, the complete mismatch between
> an expectation, an endeavor, or an execution, and the means or between
> an execution and the expectation. Trying to empty the sea with
> nutshell cups or, conversely, the stumbling of an adult when our
> empathy does not identify us with their harm or embarrassment, in
> which case we would scream, etc., etc. (Even שחק, the cheerful
> laughter, is only caused by the realization of an overcome contrast,
> an unexpectedly successful outcome, etc., etc. Even שחק, which occurs
> in the context of competitions, gymnastic exercises, and music, seems
> to stem from the joy of successfully overcoming opposing difficulties,
> thus offering a striking similarity to the other common expression for
> musical virtuosity: נַצֵח)."

Answer (score 1):

While the letters זיין and צדי can be interchangeable phonetically and each shoresh essentially means a shouting, the nature of the shout can vary.

**In the two cases mentioned above** the Targum Onkelos in Shemos and the Targum on the Megilla each indicate that the shouts of **Moshe** and **Mordechai** had a purpose of **tefila/prayer** (a lashon of צלי).

Used elsewhere it can appears with a number of meanings.

The shoresh צעק is prevalent in the Chumash.  Targum Onkelos indicates multiple shades of meaning for this word: as **צלי** = prayer, **צוח** = scream, **קבל** = complaint, and ironically in one instance, **זעק**
[image]

On the other hand the shoresh for זעק appears only twice in the Chumash but many times elsewhere - In the Chumash, Targum Onkelos identifies each instance with shouts of complaint or anguish:

> (בראשית יח:כ) וַיֹּאמֶר ה' **זַעֲקַת** סְדֹם וַעֲמֹרָה כִּי רָבָּה
> וְחַטָּאתָם כִּי כָבְדָה מְאֹד
>
> וַאֲמַר יְיָ **קְבִילַת** סְדוֹם וַעֲמוֹרָה אֲרֵי סְגִיאַת וְחוֹבַתְהוֹן אֲרֵי תְּקֵיפַת לַחְדָּא

> (שמות ב:כג) וַיְהִי בַיָּמִים הָרַבִּים הָהֵם וַיָּמׇת מֶלֶךְ
> מִצְרַיִם וַיֵּאָנְחוּ בְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל מִן הָעֲבֹדָה **וַיִּזְעָקוּ**
> וַתַּעַל שַׁוְעָתָם אֶל הָאֱלֹהִים מִן הָעֲבֹדָה
>
> וַהֲוָה בְּיוֹמַיָּא סַגִּיאַיָּא הָאִנּוּן וּמִית מַלְכָּא דְּמִצְרַיִם וְאִתְאָנַחוּ בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל מִן פּוּלְחָנָא דַּהֲוָה קְשֵׁי עֲלֵיהוֹן **וּזְעִיקוּ** וּסְלֵיקַת **קְבִילַתְהוֹן** לִקְדָם יְיָ מִן פּוּלְחָנָא

sometimes זעק is a shout to gather people together as in

> (יהושע ח:טז) **וַיִּזָּעֲקוּ** כׇּל הָעָם אֲשֶׁר בָּעַי לִרְדֹּף
> אַחֲרֵיהֶם
>
> **וְאִתְכְּנִישׁוּ** כָּל עַמָא דִי בְקַרְתָּא בָּעַי לְמִרְדַף בַּתְרֵיהוֹן (תרגום יונתן)

Elsewhere it can have some of the meanings listed above for צעק.

Comment: Very interesting, what is the application you used to search for the sharoshim?

Comment: The application is (my very own) basehasefer.com. One can search shorashim (not 100% accurate) by typing in text and selecting the shoresh button in the search options on the right before searching.  You can get to the Lexicon screen I pasted above by going directly to https://basehasefer.com/#/lexicon?&root=צעק and then clicking the Targum button on the lower left.